# MySQL: Find the last event where the user was tracked

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say your web application tracks the activities of its users using a tracking system. While a user hasn't logged in or signed up, all the user's actions are tracked using anonymous_id and the user_id is null, and afterward, they are tracked using the same anonymous_id and user_id. It is known that after a user logs in or signs up, the user_id is no longer null.

I am trying to write a query to find the last event where the user was tracked only by anonymous_id (column last_null) and the first event that was tracked by user_id (column first_notnull). The resulting table should be sorted by anonym_id.

For given table tracks;

| received_at | event_name | anonymous_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 12:13:12 | buttonClicked | 1 | NULL |
| 2016-01-02 12:14:15 | pageReloaded | 3 | NULL |
| 2016-02-02 13:15:13 | pageRendered | 2 | NULL |
| 2016-02-03 13:15:23 | commentWritten | 3 | NULL |
| 2016-03-03 14:15:15 | avatarUpdated | 2 | 2 |
| 2016-03-04 14:15:24 | statusUpdated | 1 | 1 |

Output should be;

| anonym_id | last_null | first_notnull |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | buttonClicked | statusUpdated |
| 2 | pageRendered | avatarUpdated |
| 3 | commentWritten | NULL |

Here is what I came up with, but I am not sure if there is a better solution. Can you please help me?

```
   SELECT
        distinct anonymous_id as anonym_id
       ,CASE
           WHEN user_id is not null THEN prev_event
           WHEN user_id is null THEN event_name
        END AS last_null 
       ,CASE
           WHEN user_id is not null THEN event_name
           WHEN user_id is null THEN next_event
        END AS first_notnull
       FROM(
           SELECT
               *
               ,max(rnk)
           FROM(    
                   SELECT
                       *
                       ,lag(event_name) OVER(PARTITION BY anonymous_id ORDER BY received_at ASC) as prev_event          
                       ,lead(event_name) OVER(PARTITION BY anonymous_id ORDER BY received_at ASC) as next_event
                       ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY anonymous_id ORDER BY received_at ASC) as rnk
                   FROM tracks
                   ) as temp
           GROUP BY anonymous_id
       )as temp2
WHERE prev_event is not NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to achieve this, this is one of it:

```
SELECT anonymous_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       GROUP_CONCAT(
             CASE WHEN user_id IS NULL 
                  THEN event_name END
                ORDER BY received_at DESC),',',1) AS last_null,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       GROUP_CONCAT(
             CASE WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN event_name END 
              ORDER BY received_at ASC),',',1) AS first_notnull
FROM tracks
GROUP BY anonymous_id;
```

Using `CASE` expression then wrap it in `GROUP_CONCAT()` with addition of `ORDER BY received_at DESC`. Then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the value from `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`. [See this fiddle to understand more](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b02b7a61438090f029a4da5d7efec1c)

This is the quickest I can think of right now but I'll try a few more ways (probably shorter and more efficient query) and will update the answer if necessary.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I added [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7faa7f99379061147d5463be33d91b76) more samples. FirstNotNull column is not getting populated correctly. I will try to modify your query.

Comment: Ahh, I see.. so the `GROUP_CONCAT()` for `first_notnull` should be `ORDER BY received_at ASC` instead, right? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b02b7a61438090f029a4da5d7efec1c